# Angular 2, вывести название вместо ID

Tags: angular2, typescript

пытаюсь вывести список заказов, там поля: номер заказа, дата и ID покупателя. 
не пойму, как вместо ID покупателя на клиенте отображать ФИО?
список покупателей и список заказов - это 2 сервиса.

```
    import { Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { Person } from './person';
import { Order } from './order';
import { OrderService } from './order.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Http, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
  selector: 'list-order',
  template: `      
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let order of orders">
        {{order.dateOrder}} {{order.personId}} 
      </li>
    </ul>            
  `,
  providers: [OrderService, PersonService]
})

export class ListOrderComponent implements OnInit {
  orders: Order[];
  persons: Person[];
  http: Http;

  constructor(private orderService: OrderService, private personService: PersonService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.orderService.getAllOrders().subscribe(orders => this.orders = orders);
  }
}
```

person.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Person } from './person';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class PersonService {

  constructor (private http: Http) {} 

  getPersons(): Observable<any> { 
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/persons').map(res => res.json())
  }
  }
```

с бэкенда возвращается ID и ФИО человека

Comment: Вы бы хоть часть кода показали бы чтоли...

Comment: перед выводом получи из второго сервиса фио по ID и выведи его

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: прошу прощения.

Comment: Что у вас есть в `PersonService`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам требуется загружать сначала данные о сотрудниках, после данные о заказах (это требуется для того, чтобы быть уверенными, что на момент получения данных о заказах уже будем иметь данные о сотрудниках).

Далее - при получении необходимых данных просто у каждого заказа добавить необходимые дополнительные филды (`personName`, например) и перемапить данные с их заполнением.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'list-order',
  template: `      
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let order of orders">
        {{order.dateOrder}} {{order.personName}} 
      </li>
    </ul>            
  `,
  providers: [OrderService, PersonService]
})

export class ListOrderComponent implements OnInit {
  orders: [];
  http: Http;

  constructor(private orderService: OrderService, private personService: PersonService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.personService.getPersons().subscribe(persons => {
      this.orderService.getAllOrders().subscribe(orders => {
        this.orders = orders.map(order => {
          let orderExtended = order;
          orderExtended.personName = persons.find(person => person.Id === order.personId);
          return orderExtended;
        });
      });
    });
  }
}
```

---

Либо можно выполнять запросы данных о сотрудниках и о заказах вместе:

```
export class ListOrderComponent implements OnInit {
  private allOrders: Order[];
  private allPersons: Person[];
  orders: [];
  http: Http;

  constructor(private orderService: OrderService, private personService: PersonService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.personService.getPersons().subscribe(persons => {
      this.allPersons = persons;
      tryFillOrders();
    });
    this.orderService.getAllOrders().subscribe(orders => {
      this.allOrders= orders ;
      tryFillOrders();
    });
  }

  private tryFillOrders() {
    if (!this.allOrders || !this.allPersons) {
      return;
    }

    this.orders = this.allOrders.map(order => {
      let orderExtended = order;
      orderExtended.personName = this.allPersons.find(person => person.Id === order.personId);
      return orderExtended;
    });
  }
}
```

**Но**

Лично я считаю, что это решение выглядит некрасивым и непрактичным. Если есть возможность, я бы поработал с сервером и добавлял маппинг необходимых филдов на сервере непосредственно.

Comment: спасибо! значит, сделаю на сервере

Comment: @Kate к слову, если вы на `.NET` пишите, `AutoMapper` с легкостью поможет вам без дополнительных конфигураций смаппить необходимый ответ :)

Comment: @AGS17 Зачем мапить, если в объекте order должно быть поле person?

Comment: @Alex78191 о чем вы?

Comment: @AGS17 вы же предлагали мапить

Comment: @Alex78191 если вы о [этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/671822/angular-2-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-id/671851?noredirect=1#comment976994_671851), то я просто подсказал хороший иснрумент для маппинга на стороне сервера.

Comment: @AGS17 Зачем в данном случае маппить?

Comment: @Alex78191 у вас есть полная модель сущности, которую вы используете в `Entity Framework`. Естественно, вы ее не будете возвращать, вы будете возвращать только необходимые филды. Соответсвенно, вы сделаете `DTO`шку и ее вернете. `AutoMapper` нужен для маппинга модели сущности в модель транфера. В общем, never mind.

Comment: @AGS17 Можно и полную возвращать, если объем данных небольшой. Можно создавать интерфейсы DTO и в сущности их реализовывать.

Comment: @Alex78191 я всего лишь дал вариант решения, которое использовал бы я. В любом случае, Алексей, как я уже сказал - never mind.

Comment: @AGS17 «Алекс — уменьшительная форма имён Александр, Алексей, Александра.»

Comment: @Alex78191 прошу прощения - Александр.

Comment: @AGS17 прошу называть меня Alex78191.